# Conscience in the text of the Quran and Hadith

Tags: quran, hadith, verses

Good afternoon to all participants.
Please tell me, are there any verses in the Quran that speak about conscience?
Does the word "conscience" occur in the text of the Quran?
If so, what etymological meaning does this Arabic word have?

P.s. I am reflecting on conscience, I would like to know what the text of the Quran and Hadith says about it.

Comment: 75:2: And I swear by the _self-critical soul_!?

Comment: Does it turn out that the soul acts as a judge of a person here? Does the soul judge a person for the deeds done?

Comment: النفس in Arabic is related to soul and to a breathing (living) individual SSO in the end the verse simply means a person and it's conscience.